# How to draw cube with cone (Dreidel like), using Onshape?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design

I want to draw a cube with cone using [Onshape](https://www.onshape.com/).

I need the cone to "shave" the corners of the cube, till it gets to the middle point.

This is diagram I made:

[image: Sketch]

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After rejecting the intense interrogation process for signing up with Onshape, I've settled for a general description based on common practices in 3D modeling.

You would create the rectangular solid representing the cube, as well as another rectangular (or cylindrical) solid slightly larger than the first one.

[image: three solids stacked]

Create also a cone shape with the dimensions appropriate to the segment you wish to have remaining on the first solid.

Using Boolean operator or the equivalent, subtract/difference the cone shape from the second solid, resulting in a "pencil point" shape of empty space in the second solid.

[image: cone subtracted from cube]

The skirt of the cone is barely visible in the image above and is transparent, the TinkerCAD™ version of subtraction.

Once grouped in TinkerCAD™, the entire cube becomes a subtractive body.

[image: cutting cone shape]

Place it in the appropriate position over the first solid and perform a second subtraction/difference or Boolean equivalent.

[image: adjusted and positioned shape]

As one may note, the original cube was not tall enough and had to be stretched to provide the desired result. Not visible in this image is that the subtractive shape was not centered on the cube and resulted in an off-center final solid. Easily corrected with alignment tools, but an important aspect when performing Boolean operations. Control-Z is your friend.

[image: final shape]

The above steps work with OpenSCAD™ as well as Fusion360™ and even within TinkerCAD™ but the specific steps/sequence varies from one program to the other, of course. This example was performed in TinkerCAD™ because it was the fastest method. Fusion360™ would have stretched my abilities to accomplish the same result, due to my minimal experience with that platform.

I am not surprised to discover and easily locate [an exact tutorial for OnShape™](https://www.onshape.com/cad-blog/tech-tip-booleans-in-onshape) that covers the boolean subtraction process. The images are complex within the tutorial, but the process and concepts are identical. The video accompanying the tutorial is also well done and explains clearly the steps involved.

Comment: So, basically, if you mentioned "pencil point", create something like "pencil sharpener" and use it to subtract the long cube? Did I got it right?

Comment: yes, that's a good description

Comment: Amazing, very nice thinking :), Thanks @fred_dot_u!